# My withdrawal is still verification pending after 1 week, what should I do?

Tags: transactions, withdrawal

After 910 days, I withdrew 0.205 BTC to Trust wallet. And still nothing. Any tips? What should I do? I really need this money.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9046/5406?

Comment: Welcome to bitcoin.stackexchange.com. Where/what are you withdrawing money from?

Comment: Has it been 1 week or 910 days that you are waiting for your transaction?

Comment: It was from a free roll BTC website and its totally leggal. Put effort for 910 days and when i withdraw it says verifacation pending for 1 week and more

Comment: You have been scammed. Transactions on the Bitcoin network never have "verification pending" - that must be an invention of the "free roll BTC website" you were using

Comment: no it iz imposible bcz my friend withdraw from fhe same site and he got the money my uncle did the same too